# 'dict' object has no attribute 'META' redirect error

Tags: python, django

sorry for typos, I'm using translation

I want to integrate virtual pos for payment method, but the error I got is as follows

Error;
**'dict' object has no attribute 'META'**

views.py:

```
@login_required(login_url="/user/login")
def payment(request):
    options = {
        'api_key': 'api_key',
        'secret_key': 'secret_key',
        'base_url': 'sandbox-api.iyzipay.com'
    }
    
    
    payment_card = {
        'cardHolderName': 'John Doe',
        'cardNumber': '5528790000000008',
        'expireMonth': '12',
        'expireYear': '2030',
        'cvc': '123',
        'registerCard': '0'
    }
    
    buyer = {
        'id': 'BY789',
        'name': 'John',
        'surname': 'Doe',
        'gsmNumber': '+905350000000',
        'email': 'email@email.com',
        'identityNumber': '74300864791',
        'lastLoginDate': '2015-10-05 12:43:35',
        'registrationDate': '2013-04-21 15:12:09',
        'registrationAddress': 'Nidakule Göztepe, Merdivenköy Mah. Bora Sok. No:1',
        'ip': '85.34.78.112',
        'city': 'Istanbul',
        'country': 'Turkey',
        'zipCode': '34732'
    }
    
    address = {
        'contactName': 'Jane Doe',
        'city': 'Istanbul',
        'country': 'Turkey',
        'address': 'Nidakule Göztepe, Merdivenköy Mah. Bora Sok. No:1',
        'zipCode': '34732'
    }
    
    basket_items = [
        {
            'id': 'BI101',
            'name': 'Binocular',
            'category1': 'Collectibles',
            'category2': 'Accessories',
            'itemType': 'PHYSICAL',
            'price': '0.3'
        },
        {
            'id': 'BI102',
            'name': 'Game code',
            'category1': 'Game',
            'category2': 'Online Game Items',
            'itemType': 'VIRTUAL',
            'price': '0.5'
        },
        {
            'id': 'BI103',
            'name': 'Usb',
            'category1': 'Electronics',
            'category2': 'Usb / Cable',
            'itemType': 'PHYSICAL',
            'price': '0.2'
        }
    ]
    
    request = {
        'locale': 'tr',
        'conversationId': '123456789',
        'price': '1',
        'paidPrice': '1.2',
        'currency': 'TRY',
        'installment': '1',
        'basketId': 'B67832',
        'paymentChannel': 'WEB',
        'paymentGroup': 'PRODUCT',
        'paymentCard': payment_card,
        'buyer': buyer,
        'shippingAddress': address,
        'billingAddress': address,
        'basketItems': basket_items
    }
    
    payment = iyzipay.Payment().create(request, options)
    return render(request, "cart/payment.html")
```

brokerage firm codes;
https://github.com/iyzico/iyzipay-python

Maybe you can condemn me for attempting such a job without knowing the basics :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You changed the value of *request* in your code in line

```
request = {'locale': 'tr',...
```

This causes the line

```
return render(request, "cart/payment.html")
```

to use the modified value of *request*, instead of the value in

```
def payment(request):
```

Try to change the name of your request variable to something different

ex:

```
request_api = {'locale': 'tr',...
payment = iyzipay.Payment().create(request_api, options)
```

Answer (score 0):

You override the `request` variable with your custom dict, due to which you are getting the meta data error.

Change the dict variable name `request` to something `request_payload` such as :

```
request_payload = {
    'locale': 'tr',
    'conversationId': '123456789',
    'price': '1',
    'paidPrice': '1.2',
    'currency': 'TRY',
    'installment': '1',
    'basketId': 'B67832',
    'paymentChannel': 'WEB',
    'paymentGroup': 'PRODUCT',
    'paymentCard': payment_card,
    'buyer': buyer,
    'shippingAddress': address,
    'billingAddress': address,
    'basketItems': basket_items
}
payment = iyzipay.Payment().create(request_payload, options)
return render(request, "cart/payment.html")
```

Thats it.

Comment: Thanks for both comments my problem is solved